# tm package installation in R-Studio

Tags: r

How can I install "tm"(for text analysis) package in R-Studio? When I tried, it shows the following warning.

"Warning in install.packages :
package ‘tm’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)"

I tried to click "Check for update" the "R" but it is telling "All packages are up to date"
Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: it might help to update your version of R; it's several years old ...

Comment: Just go to `r-project.org` and download the latest binary for your OS. Then restart RStudio and rerun the install function. It should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same problem. So sharing the solution that worked for me. Hope it helps

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9`

//to add the key of the developer

In your `vi /etc/apt/sources.list` add the following line

deb http:///bin/linux/ubuntu precise/

you can get the mirrors from http://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

next step for you is to update apt
using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and now your R is upgraded to the latest version and now you can install tm using the command you have used

taken from http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README